# objective c - want to get latitude and longitude value and write to GET parameters

Tags: objective-c, ios

Noob question here - I googled but came up with a couple of contradictory answers. I am instantiating CoreLocation and would like to write the latitude and longitude into a url to do a get against a remove service. I have:

```
if([CLLocationManager locationServicesEnabled]){
  self.myLocationManager=[[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
  self.myLocationManager.delegate=self;
  self.myLocationManager.purpose = @"To provide functionality based on user's current location";
  [self.myLocationManager startUpdatingLocation];
}else{
  NSLog(@"Location services are not enabled");
}

NSString *urlAsString=@"http://localhost:3000/";
urlAsString = [urlAsString stringByAppendingString:@"?latitude=my-latitude"];
urlAsString = [urlAsString stringByAppendingString:@"&longititude=my-longitude"];
NSURL *url=[NSURL URLWithString:urlAsString];
```

How would I write latitude and longitude into the URL requeset correctly? Do I need to instantiate a new NSString for the stringByAppendingString?

thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It might be easier to use string formatting:

```
NSString *urlAsString = [NSString
    stringWithFormat:"http://localhost:3000/?latitude=%g&longitude=%g", 
    location.coordinate.latitude,
    location.coordinate.longitude];
```

I have used the formatting specifier `%g` assuming that you get your values from a [`CLLocation`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocation_Class/CLLocation/CLLocation.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007126) instance.

Comment: cool, something like this looks about right. I would need to do this after the didUpdateToLocation, right?

Answer (score 1):

The CLLocation class (which is what you get from the location manager) has a coordinate property which has both the latitude and longitude.

```
NSLog(@"Current Latitude: %f, Current Longitude: %f",location.coordinate.latitude,location.coordinate.longitude);
```

will output both so assuming that in your code:

```
urlAsString = [urlAsString stringByAppendingString:@"?latitude=my-latitude"];
```

you want to change the my-latitude for a number, all you have to do is

```
NSString *urlAsString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://localhost:3000/?latitude=%f&longitude=%f",location.coordinate.latitude,location.coordinate.longitude];
```

This is considering that your CCLocation object is called "location"