# couldn't find latitude and longitude of my iphone

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode4

i am trying to find out iphone's current location and for this I am using this method. and try to save it for further procedure. but when I print value of location in form of latitude and longitude  It always giving me 0.00000 and 0.0000. I am not getting the point that where I am wrong.this method is save in GetLocation class.

```
-(void)updatelocation{

NSLog(@"coming in update location    in get location class");
locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
locationManager.delegate = self;
locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone;
[locationManager startUpdatingLocation];

NSLog(@"location manager   %@", locationManager);
CLLocation *location = [locationManager location];
CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate = [location coordinate];
NSString *latitude = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", coordinate.latitude];
NSString *longitude = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", coordinate.longitude];

NSLog(@"Latitude is: %f\n\n\n and longitude is: %f\n\n\n", location.coordinate.latitude, location.coordinate.longitude);
NSLog(@"coordinate   %f",coordinate.latitude);
NSUserDefaults *defaults=[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[defaults setObject:latitude forKey:@"latitude"];
[defaults setObject:longitude forKey:@"longitude"];

}
```

when I call this method in another class like this.

```
GetLocation *location = [GetLocation alloc] init ];
[location updatelocation];
```

but I always get 0.0000 and 0.0000. can anybody tell me that where  I am wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at the [-[CLLocation coordinate] documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocation_Class/CLLocation/CLLocation.html) first...and even [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9730707/objective-c-want-to-get-latitude-and-longitude-value-and-write-to-get-paramete)...

Answer (score 3):

You are going too fast, the `CLLocationManager` hasn't determined your location yet. You should implement `CLLocationManagerDelegate`'s `locationManager:didUpdateToLocation:fromLocation:` method. In that method, the user's location **is** known.

Comment: I am getting your point that its too fast. can you write syntax that how to use locationManager :didUpdateToLocation:fromLocation.
because I didn't get this method.

Comment: @ArpitRaniwala: Have you at least *tried* implementing the method? Read the API reference, try implementing it, and *then* ask for help (posting your attempted code) if you get stuck.